Propositional logic based on sets of propositions
I was just reading about Wittgenstein's generalization of NOR to apply to a set of propositions. To invent my own notation:
NOR{P1, P2, ..., Pn} -- true iff none of the Pi are true
This got me wondering about other multi-proposition operators such as
OR {P1, P2, ..., Pn} -- true iff at least one of the Pi is true
AND {P1, P2, ..., Pn} -- true iff all of the Pi are true
XOR {P1, P2, ..., Pn} -- true iff exactly one of the Pi is true
FXOR {P1, P2, ..., Pn} -- true iff exactly one of the Pi is false
etc. Are there any treatments of this general idea?
ADDENDUM
The answers and comments seem to be approaching this from the point of view of traditional logic concerns, but those concerns aren't what prompted the question. I used to design programming languages, so what interested me about the idea was not its logical properties but what might be called its pragmatic properties, its power to express complex notions in a simple and readable form. For example, try expressing XOR{P1,P2,P3} using binary predicates. You will find it's quite complex and a bit difficult to understand.

n-ary logical connectives are more commonly called Boolean functions (for classical logic, there are generalizations), and there is an extensive theory of them. In particular, they can always be written in conjunctive or disjunctive normal form, which use only conjunctions, disjunctions and negations. Those forms can be read off directly from the kinds of word descriptions that you give, i.e. from truth tables.

For finite sets of propositions, not really useful: AND (P1, P2, P3) is simply AND (AND (P1,P2), P3).

Original W's approach is to apply them to infinite collection of propositions: in that way, quantifiers can be reduced to boolean connectives: the universal quantifier is nothing more than an infinite conjunction... See e.g. Gregory Landini, Tractarian Logicism: Operations, Numbers, Induction (The Review of Symbolic Logic, 2020)

Also James Connelly, On Operator N and Wittgenstein’s Logical Philosophy (2017)

This is just predicate logic, with quantors, right? What would this buy you that you can't get from predicate logic? Isn't Wittgenstein's remark simply a remark on what predicate logic is?

You can generalise a connective to multiple arguments if it is associative and commutative. This works for conjunction (∧), inclusive or (∨), exclusive or (⊻) and material equivalence (↔). The truth conditions are as follows for a set of propositions Γ

∨(Γ) is true iff for at least one x ∊ Γ, x is true.
∧(Γ) is false iff for at least one x ∊ Γ, x is false.
⊻(Γ) is true iff an odd number of the sentences in Γ is true.
↔(Γ) is false iff an odd number of the sentences in Γ is false.

From this we get the following corollaries.

If the cardinality of Γ is odd, then it contains an even number of true sentences and an odd number of false sentences, or vice versa. In either case, the truth tables for ⊻(Γ) and ↔(Γ) are identical.
If the cardinality of Γ is even, the number of true sentences and the number of false sentences it contains are either both even or both odd. In either case, the truth tables for ⊻(Γ) and ↔(Γ) are inverses of one another.
If Γ is a singleton set {A} then the truth values of each of ∨(Γ), ∧(Γ), ⊻(Γ), and ↔(Γ) are identical with the truth value of A.
If Γ is null, then we get:  ∨(ø) = ⊥,   ∧(ø) = ⊤,    ⊻(ø) = ⊥,   ↔(ø) = ⊤

The NOR connective is not associative, so you cannot extend it this way. So, Wittgenstein's proposed N-operator is not the same.

I don't think your proposed way of extending the xor operator is interesting or useful, which is why I chose the one I did. There are lots of cases where "exactly one of these" is true. For example you throw a die to get result x, then XOR{x=1,x=2,x=3,x=4,x=5,x=6} is true.

I think you may be missing the point. What I am presenting are the truth conditions of the ⊻-closure of a set of sentences Γ. I.e. the truth conditions of A ⊻ B ⊻ C ⊻ D ... Ditto for the other connectives. It is not a question of whether they are interesting or useful: those are what you get when you close a set of sentences under the connectives. There is no complete truth functional connective that extends NOR in the way Wittgenstein proposes or extends ⊻ in the way you propose. You would need to use second order logic and quantify over sentences or else use arithmetic.

What do you mean, "There is no complete truth functional connective"? Also, whatever that means, it's probably not what I was going for. I'm not looking to just extend the existing truth  functions, but to explore the  new types of truth functions that you can get by allowing an arbitrary number of arguments.

Why do we need the initial binary connective to be commutative, or even associative for that matter? Starting from any binary connective one can simply specify an association rule. So → is neither commutative nor associative, but ((a → b) → c) → d is a quaternary connective. And n-ary connective can be generated for any n on the same pattern. But why even bother with composing binary connectives? CDNF can be directly written for any n-ary connective, including the OP's n-NOR. It is just the conjunction of negated variables.

I mean that Wittgenstein's N-operator is not a composition of any binary connective and it is not functionally complete (see section 5a of the IEP article you linked). In particular, it is not an extension of the Sheffer stroke that expresses the binary NOR. One could of course choose not to bother with composing binary connectives, as @Conifold suggests, but the price is extra complexity. It is highly convenient to be able to speak of the closure of a set of propositions under a relation. I should perhaps have made it clearer that I was speaking of this kind of extension.

With XOR, the situation is even more complex. We could devise some normal form that corresponds to "exactly one is true", but why should that be considered the extension of XOR? Why not, "at least one is true but not all"? Or, "exactly one is false"? Usually the natural way to extend a connective is to compose it with itself, though there are exceptions. Quantifying over a set of propositions is messy. As Wittgenstein himself pointed out in a later criticism of the Tractatus, a universally quantified expression is not equivalent to a conjunction unless you add, "and that's all there are".

@Bumble, I believe an operation that says that set of possibilities are exhaustive and mutually exclusive is inherently useful for what I'm after, but don't think I explained myself very well so I've added an addendum to the question to explain my goal better.
